# ssh-copy-id error: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Tags: ssh

I've just created a public key on a FreeBSD machine (10.3-STABLE) using `ssh-keygen` and I'm trying to use it on another machine (same OS):

`> ssh-copy-id '-p XXX user@host'
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
no keys found`

OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1t-freebsd 3 May 2016 (both machines)

I've tried many variants of specifying the port. ame result.

What is the problem?

Comment: What key do you want to copy? What openssh version are you using?

Comment: I want to copy a standart public key - /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: @Jakuje How do I find out which version of openssh I use?

Comment: depends on what os are you using (which is also good to know).

Comment: @Jakue FreeBSD 10.3-STABLE (added this info to the question as well)

Comment: `ssh -V` should give you information about openssh version. Though just unsetting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable should do the job.

Comment: @Jakue OpenSSH_7.2p2, OpenSSL 1.0.1t-freebsd  3 May 2016
(both machines)